# How to trigger a method call every x minutes in Scala?

Tags: scala, cron, playframework-2.0

I'm planning a mechanism whose usage scenarios would be like cron's. It's a clock-ish mechanism that attempts task execution at prespecified times. Cron doesn't seem suitable, because these tasks trigger Scala method calls and the queue stored on a cloud database.

I imagine it like this: every x minutes, tasks' execution dates are retrieved from the database, and compared against current time, if the task is over-due it is executed and removed from queue.

My question is: *how do I run the aforementioned check every x minutes on a distributed environment?*

All advice encouraged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Akka scheduler might be what you are looking for.  Here's a [link to the Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/scheduler.html) and here's another link describing [how to use Akka in Play](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaAkka).

Update: as Viktor Klang points out Akka is *not* a scheduler, however it does allow you to run a task periodically.  I've used it in this mode quite successfully.

Comment: The Akka Scheduler is not intended for that, it's intended for running things "after" an elapsed X time, not AT time X.

Comment: Is it intended or not, but you can calculate the time difference between current time and the scheduled time and schedule the task for that difference which will get you the time "AT"

Comment: @Viktor, if you read my question, you'll see that this is exactly what I need: check queue every x time.

Comment: @serejja Yes, you can do that. I just wanted to make sure that it is understood that the Scheduler does not run "on", it runs "after".

Answer (score 1):

The best known library for this is [Quartz Scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/).

Comment: I didn't explicitly mention this, but context is Web application in a distributed environment built on Scala and Play2 framework. Akka scheduler seems to be the way to go, considering how well it integrates with those other tools.